# Rails dependent: :destroy on belongs to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

```
# photo.rb
belongs_to :batch, inverse_of: :photos

# batch.rb
has_many :photos, inverse_of: :batch
```

I wanted to have a batch destroyed only when it's last photo is destroyed.

```
# photo.rb
belongs_to :batch, inverse_of: :photos, dependent: :destroy
```

Will delete the batch if I destroy any of it's photos. Is there any easy way to do this in rails? or do I have to do something ugly like handle it in `photos#destroy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be done manually. The following code is for Rails 4.x.

An easy way to do it is to use an `after_destroy` filter in the photo model to check if the parent batch is empty, and if so, destroy it.

```
# photo.rb

after_destroy :destroy_empty_batch

def destroy_empty_batch
  batch.destroy if batch.photos.empty?
end
```

**However, it is bad design to allow one model to manipulate objects of another model.** The proper way to do it is in the controller. Instead of using a filter in the model, just add two lines to the photos controller:

```
# photos_controller.rb

def destroy
  batch = @photo.batch            # set a batch pointer
  @photo.destroy                  
  batch.destroy if @batch.empty?  # check batch, destroy if empty
  # ...respond_to block...     
end
```

Comment: Sounds about right. Just wanted to confirm I wasn't missing something better.